# File service latency is high, How to troubleshoot?

Tags: file, http, tcp, upload, tcpdump

This service is a file upload service, and the request packet capture in the live network is as follows:
Expressed as:

1. The data uploaded by the client is halfway through, and then it will not be sent.
2. The server sends keep alive to maintain the heartbeat
3. After 30 seconds, the client uploads the data again.
   Ask the boss how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic here (unrelated to programming), try superuser.com instead.  But I doubt that one can help you based on the details provided. Given that the client is the one slowly sending the data you need to look at the client side to find out why the client is doing this. Nothing is known about the client though.